# is a method parameter implicit? - using scala 2.10 reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

Given a reflected method:

```
scala> val sortMethod = typeOf[::[_]].member(newTermName("sorted"))
sortMethod: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = method sorted

scala> sortMethod.typeSignature
res122: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = [B >: A](implicit ord: scala.math.Ordering[B])Repr
```

What's the best way to find out if the method has implicit parameters (in scala 2.10-M4+)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, I don't think that you can. `isImplicit` was [added 6 days ago](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/027b00171c0d92ec669deaa471966e6468c6b8cf), so you should be able to with a nightly build or in the next milestone release.

Answer (score 6):

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val sortMethod = typeOf[::[_]].member(newTermName("sorted")).asMethod
sortMethod: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = method sorted

scala> sortMethod.params // `params` has been added only a few days ago
res0: List[List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol]] = List(List(value ord))

scala> sortMethod.params(0)(0).asTerm.isImplicit
res2: Boolean = true

scala> sortMethod.params(0)(0) hasFlag Flag.IMPLICIT
res3: Boolean = true
```

If you ask me what way to prefer, I'd advise to go with `isXXX` methods. First of all, that's a consistent way of testing, because there's only a dozen or so public flags, but there are much more things to test (e.g. `isStable` or `isSynthetic`). Secondly, flags are trickier than they look (e.g. several flag names might correspond to the same bit in the flag mask), so `isXXX` methods provide better encapsulation.